# How to access static file system inside karaf from bundle deployed

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

We are using Karaf for Camel-Blueprint Application.

We want to access Karaf_Home_DIR/Config from one of the bundle we deployed in Karaf Container.

How can we access , no idea and not getting clear information anywhere ...

Comment: You can use java.io.File to read from the file system and that way read in that folder. Karaf set some ENV or JVM system variable with its home dir.

Comment: Got it thanks , its issue with my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use File API as said by Claus. it will usually point to Karaf Root / Home Directory.

Answer (score 2):

As previous answers said, you can use java File API. But be careful when specifying the file path.

Remember that your application can run on an other environment, so the file path must be independent from your local machine (portability).

I suggest you to put this file in the karaf etc folder and access it like this:

```
File file = new File( System.getProperty( "karaf.etc" ) + File.separator + PATH + "your file name" );
```